# ASP .NET AD Authentication with LDAP

Tags: .net, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I started an internship at a company and the project that I'm working on requires me to access an Active Directory (through Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) to access user credentials and to deal with authorization and authentication. What authentication template should I use from the ones available?

[image]

I tried using Work and School Accounts (which would've been perfect) but the AD domain that I'm using was not configured properly and the following error appears:

[image]

So, this leaves me with the other 3 options, and I'm not sure what I should be using, or if it is best to code it from scratch.

PS: I'm using the 4.6.1 .NET Framework.

Comment: Not clear about the requirements. Why do you have to use LDAP? Using Windows authentication would use the logged in Windows user account to populate the ClaimsPrincipal with claims from AD. If that is enough for you, this is the simplest solution.

Comment: @MvdD So what you're saying is that Windows Authentication is in fact querying the AD? I can use it instead of LDAP?

Comment: yes, select that option and check the claims in System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal. If that has the info you need, there's no need for LDAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to develop and intranet application, that uses an established Active Directory database, you should use the Windows Authentication option as that takes care of the authentication for you.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus I've changed it.